# Windows 8 Message Window

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Windows 8 has a new message window that displays in the top right side of the screen.  Does Delphi XE4 have any API to access this new feature?

Comment: That's only for Modern-Style Windows Store Apps (Metro)

Comment: Are you sure this is true?  I ask this because the window also appears on the desktop.  If it is only for Metro, is there a Metro API for its use?

Comment: If this feature is accessible from a native Win32 application (using the Windows API, for instance), then you can use it in *any* version of Delphi.

Comment: First of all you need to find out what this feature is called. Then you'll be able to find the developer docs. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of dialog is part of the [Windows.UI.Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208661) namespace which belongs to the WinRT,  and unfortunately you cannot access the WinRT from Delphi directly. but maybe you can try this article to check a sample with experimental access to the WinRT from Delphi,  [Writing Hello World for WinRT in Delphi](http://www.thomgerdes.com/2011/12/writing-hello-world-for-winrt-in-delphi.html)

Comment: I am running Windows 8 not RT.  Are you saying Windows 8 is calling WinRT methods?

Comment: I'm saying that Windows 8 introduces a new API called WinRT (and also maintains the WinAPIO) which is not accessible from Delphi directly. and the dialog which you want to invoke resides inside of the WinRT.

Comment: @RRUZ No viable way to target WinRT from Delphi. The article you link to was for dev preview. Since then WinRT has been locked down. Needs to use a .net language, or MS C++.

Answer (score 1):

This is `Notifications` or `Toasts`, you can find a C++ and C# example here - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2

I've yet to see a direct Delphi implementation of this which is why I can only suggest the C++/C# version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hopefully one of the C guys can develop an example for Delphi... looking forward to that....

Comment: Why don't you do that? If you want to develop on Windows you need to learn how to read its native language.

Comment: @David. I have been developing with Pascal for over 30 years... I am an old timer not eager to learn C... that is the only reason.  I have developed thousands of apps over the years without it.  I know a little, but not enough to convert it.

Comment: You're never too old to learn. I think it's a shame that you cut yourself off from new skills.

Comment: Does C cost very much?

Comment: Well, the sample code is in either C++ or C#, neither or which are C. There are multiple freely available C++ and C# compilers and IDEs. One obvious choice is Visual Studio Express.